# Deploying Flask App to Heroku - ImportError Flask not found

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have some experience with Python Flask, but have only done local development. I am now messing around with Heroku to try and get some Flask projects on the web however I am having trouble even deploying a basic `HelloWorld` Flask application to Heroku. Right now my issue seems to be that it isn't processing the requirements right.

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: python hello.py
```

and my hello.py file looks like this:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

I have an updated version of requirements.txt generated from `pip freeze > requirements.txt` with Flask in it however when I type `heroku ps` in the toolbelt command line it crashes and gives me this in the log:

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 'python hello.py'
app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named flask
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]: from flask import Flask
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I cannot figure out how to get around this error that seems to be the thing stopping successful deployment, and when visiting the application site online, I obviously am met with the Application error saying my application cannot be served.

Any ideas as to why the processing of requirements may not be working correctly?

Thanks

Edit:

Add requirements.txt:

```
Flask==0.10.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.10.1
```

Comment: Can you post your requirements.txt?

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, editied...

Comment: Sometimes Heroku versions of the packages are different than yours. Can you try removing the version numbers from your requirements.txt (ie just `Flask` instead of `Flask==0.10.1` etc.) for all packages?

Comment: Yes, got rid of the all package versions and still running into the same error, No module named flask

Comment: When you run `heroku logs` what do you see for when it's deploying? Is it installing your dependencies?

Comment: It has the ImportError twice in a row, then it crashes again when `Starting process with command 'pip freeze' `...After this is says the status goes from starting to up, and from up to complete...it then waits for client info and says `heroku[router] at='error', desc='App-crashhed'`..it does this whole cycle about three times ending with a crash...But after the `pip freeze` 'error' when it says its up and running, when it tries to restart again it gets another ImportError

Answer (score 0):

maybe remove the capitalization from Flask, to flask in the requirements.txt? but thats just whats always worked for me.